# Disable Norton Idle-time Scan Notification Pop-up?

Tags: notifications, popups, norton-internet-security

I recently updated to Norton Internet Security v.19.7.1.5. Anytime the computer is idle, like when I am watching a video, this notification pops-up from the lower right corner.

I did some research, changed some settings (the screen shot is below), but it didn't fix the problem. Do you know how to disable this pop-up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you are showing are for the Scheduled Scan(s), not the Idle Scan you are seeing the pop-up for.

According to Symantec [here](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/1.6/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?docid=v15624612_NIS_Retail_2012_en_us&version=current&product=Norton+Internet+Security&ssdcat=273&spskup=21192437&spskum=21192437&spefsku=21171505&psn=KJ64HT9TFRHK&plang=sym%3AEN&oslang=iso%3APER&oslocale=iso%3AIRN&vendid=0&PartnerID=33230&tsid=4294967295&lg=english&ct=united+states&ablr=1&pvid=f-nis-cur), you can use "Slient Mode" to silence those Idle-Scan popups for a selected duration of time.

> **To turn on Silent Mode from the Settings window**
>
> 1. In the Norton Internet Security main window, click Settings.
> 2. In the Settings window, click the General tab.
> 3. In the left pane, click Silent Mode Settings.
> 4. In the Silent Mode row, move the On/Off switch to the left to the On position.
> 5. In the Settings window, click Apply.
> 6. In the Turn on Silent Mode dialog box, in the Select the duration drop-down list, select how long you want to turn on Silent Mode, and
>      then click OK.
> 7. In the Settings window, click OK.

Or

> **To turn on Silent Mode from the notification area**
>
> 1. In the notification area on the Windows taskbar, right-click the Norton Internet Security icon, and then click Turn on Silent Mode.
> 2. In the Turn on Silent Mode dialog box, in the Select the duration drop-down list, select how long you want to turn on Silent Mode, and
>      then click OK.

Comment: Great, thank you. I made the changes, and set the duration to 2 hours. But does this mean there will not be background activities during idle time? I don't mind scanning during idle time, I don't want to see the pop-up. Thanks again.

Comment: Silent Mode only disables the pop-ups themselves.  As quoted from the provided page: "After Silent Mode is turned off, Norton Internet Security also _displays alerts if it detected any security activities that occurred during the Silent Mode session_."  :)

Comment: Actually this disables the pop up for only briefly. After the time is up the pop up is back. Do you know a permanent solution?