# How to revert to older version of Norton Internet Security?

Tags: norton-antivirus, norton-internet-security

This is a follow up to my other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/443438/how-to-disable-norton-idle-time-scan-notification-pop-up). Unfortunately, Norton does not allow permanent disabling of the annoying notification pop up. You can only disable it at most for a day.

If this is not possible, I would like to ask how to remove Norton and your suggestions of an alternative.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes they do!  Uninstall Norton!  No more Popup!! Taa Daa!  They supply a nifty "Norton Removal Tool" to rid yourself of their pesky software too...  `ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/removal_tools/Norton_Removal_Tool.exe`  (WinXP/Vista/7/8 version)  Search Norton's site for "Removal Tool" to find more information.

Comment: What do you use instead of norton?

Comment: linux.  Oh, sorry..  There's a zillion to choose from, AVG is ok, and unfortunately that's the only one that comes to mind, since it's the only one I keep on my "No-I-Won't-Fix-Your-Computer" keychain flash drive. {Sigh}.  Norton & McAfee are huge resource hogs, drive space, cpu cycles and memory.  Try several of the better rated AV's, you'll be surprised how spritely your computer can be.  (I DO recommend [MalwareBytes](malwarebytes.org) and [SpyBotS&D](spybot.info) though)  Good luck.

Comment: Is it possible to revert to the previous version?

Comment: Doubt it.  Even if you COULD find one, it would nag you about upgrading to newest.  Gotta make their money!!  Best to just dump it and find a nice, less resource hungry AV.   Search around on here, someone's GOT to have asked.  It's somewhat subjective though, everyone has their favorite.  I just fix Windows Machines, I don't use one. (or own one!)

Comment: Do you mind turning your comments into an answer so that I can choose it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do! Uninstall Norton! No more Popup!! Taa Daa!

They supply a nifty "Norton Removal Tool" to rid yourself of their pesky software too...

[Norton Removal Tool](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/removal_tools/Norton_Removal_To%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bol.exe) - Latest WinXP/Vista/7/8 version

Search Norton's site for "**Removal Tool**" to find more information.

---

### What do you use instead of norton?

linux.

Oh, sorry.. There's a zillion to choose from, [AVG (free)](http://free.avg.com) and [AVG (pay)](http://www.avg.com) are ok, and unfortunately that's the only one that comes to mind, since it's the only one I keep on my "*No-I-Won't-Fix-Your-Computer*" keychain flash drive. {Sigh}.

Norton & McAfee are huge resource hogs, drive space, cpu cycles and memory.

Try several of the better rated AV's, you'll be surprised how spritely your computer can be.

(I DO recommend [MalwareBytes](http://malwarebytes.org) and [SpyBotS&D](http://spybot.info) though)

Good luck.

---

### Is it possible to revert to the previous version?

Doubt it.

Even if you COULD find one, it would **nag** you about upgrading to newest. Gotta make their money!!

Best to just dump it and find a nice, less resource hungry AV. Search around on here, someone's GOT to have asked. It's somewhat subjective though, everyone has their favorite.

I just fix Windows Machines, I don't use one. (or own one!)

Comment: MS Security essentials is a pretty good, reasonably light, free AV that dosen't nag.Its also plain old AV, no additional crap. That said, i've found that norton in most cases results in massive performance dips on systems.

Comment: Thanks. I removed norton and installed MS Security Essentials. So far so good. Installation was easy and simple. During installation it asked me to turn on Windows firewall and I did.

Comment: Hooray! It's like having a whole new computer again!