# Do I need to turn on Windows Firewall with MS Security Essentials

Tags: windows-vista, anti-virus, windows-firewall

I recently switched from Norton to MS Security Essentials ([See my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/444813/how-to-revert-to-older-version-of-norton-internet-security)). During installation I checked to activate Windows Firewall (recommended) but now I get the Firewall notice of warning to allow sites that I have been using for years. Do I really need Windows firewall? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *Allow sites*?

Comment: I didn't take a screen capture but the message said "Windows Firewall has blocked some features of this program" then I chose "unblock". Not sure what is blocked because the page opened (a live stream of a tv channel).

Comment: Hmm, you *should* only need to allow them once; then Windows Firewall should create an exception for it.

Comment: yes, the firewall did not ask again. I was wondering how do I decide to unblock and why when I was using norton there was no problem but firewall asked this message.

Comment: Because Windows Firewall has no idea what settings Norton had (there is no settings-import function), so you have to tell it what you do and don’t want to allow all over again (once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a rule to allow the program that the site is using and you won't get the message anymore.

Without knowing which websites this happens on, I can't say directly which program you need to allow.

Comment: so, do you recommend to keep the windows firewall?

Comment: @Zeynel, yes of course. You should use both because there mutually exclusive programs and neither one encompasses the domain of the other. One watches the incoming and outgoing connections to the system while the other merely scans files for bad stuff.

Comment: Yes, exactly what @Synetech said.